# Finding radius of convergence of meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to find the radius of convergence of

$$\frac{z^3-1}{z^2+3z-4}$$

This has a removable discontinuity at $z=1$ as

$$\frac{z^3-1}{z^2+3z-4}=\frac{(z-1)(z^2+z+1)}{(z-1)(z+4)}=\frac{z^2+z+1}{z+4}$$

but where do I go from here, there are no coefficients to use ratio test.I know for this to converge, the modulus needs to be less than $1$.  So do I make an inequality with the numerator and denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it has a simple pole in $z=-4$, the laurent series of the function is on the form
$$\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}a_n(z+4)^n$$ with $a_{-1}\not=0$, which is convergent in any puntued disc on the form $B_r(-4) \setminus \{-4\}$ for every radius $r>0$. More precisely the laurents series around $z=-4$ is
$$\frac{13}{z+4}-3+z$$

Comment: so you mean the convergence is on $B_r(-4) \setminus \{-4\}$, makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that means a puntued disc

Comment: in your Laurent series, you mean $z$ , not $x$, correct?

Comment: Also, in the Laurent series, is it a plus, not a minus?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo

Comment: How did you get that the Laurent series expansion about $z=-4$ is $\frac{13}{z+4}-3+z$?

Comment: $\frac{z^2+z+1}{z+4}=13/(z+4)-3+z$. Also you can compute it the usual way for Laurent series, but that's messier

Comment: but where does the $-3+z$ come in, I see the $13/z+4$. Did you decompose it?

Comment: and as the order of the simple pole is $1$, your Laurent series starts at $-1$ to $\infty$, correct?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see all terms for $n\geq 2$ are zero. With a single pole you have only guaranteed that the series starts at $-1$ with that term non zero

Comment: AHA so what your wrote down is the entire expansion ?? How did you determine the $n=0$ term to being $-3$? and how did you determine the $n=1$ term to be $z$. Sorry for asking so many questions :/ did you use the coefficient formula?

Comment: In this case is not required, just divide the polynomials so you get that $z^2+z+1=(z-3)(z+4)+13$